# Interact with GUI Elements of a Windows Application

Tags: windows, shell, user-interface, chess

First of all, I want to appreciate the work for the SCIDvsPC Project. I know that the basic SCID one has been discontinued many years back and the developer have done a great job with expanding it and doing his share for the Chess Field. We have a Minor Project to do in this 6th semester of our college. We've decided to start a project on a Chess Next Move Analyzer that is based on variety of filters and implements Self Learning and Machine Learning.

I've been researching over the project idea for the last 2 months. Actually we need to import several games defined on some filters and read and analyze from the PGN file generated. For example, if the user chooses to get the next best move predicted according to the rating range of 2000-2500, our program should only export and analyze the PGN files that have both the opponents from this range only. I know the project can do all this but I'm confused over how to automate this. I mean I have to manually enter the moves and then click on 'Generate PGN' but how to make my program do this ie take input from the user (like first 3 moves), make the project run these moves (what I had to manually) and then generate the PGN file and keep it in a folder.

I've surfed the net about interacting with GUI elements in Windows (we have no problem in working with Linux either) and came to know about Microsoft UI Automation, Python, Java and C# softwares and something like COM. Do the software support COM or any one of these or have you already developed some functionality like this? Please can you guide me over this?

If asked to Generalize this what I want to do is to interact with GUI Elements, be it any application. Take Notepad as an example. Suppose I want to open a file on it, find and replace a particular word. Now, I know how to do this manually but when I have over thousands of file I need some kind of program to do this for me. Do some specific programs like SCID in my case has some feature (read bit about COM) pre-built to handle this? In which programming language domain does this come into? Is using Linux help me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Take Notepad as an example. Suppose I want to open a file on it, find
>   and replace a particular word. Now, I know how to do this manually but
>   when I have over thousands of file I need some kind of program to do
>   this for me.  Do some specific programs like SCID in my case has some
>   feature (read bit about COM) pre-built to handle this?

- Your situation sounds to be quite specific so I doubt whether you will be able to find a pre-existing program to do this for you. Meaning: you'll have to code it yourself.

> In which programming language domain does this come into?

- Well, this could probably be done in many, many different programming languages. A simple shell script would be able to achieve the Notepad example you gave.

> Is using Linux help me more?

- No, your goals seem to be pretty achievable by a simple shell script, whether you write it in a Windows, macOS or a Linux distro.

Answer (score 1):

@SB87 gave you some useful hints, I'd like to expand his answers.

- Sorry, I **don't think** you know what you're talking about. Reinforcement learning (better term than self-learning) and machine learning are not something suitable for a college project. It's at the PhD or research level, consider getting yourself into university before even thinking about anything like that.
- UI automation is possible, but error prone and slow. If you want to do it, you'd write a console program. You mentioned something about user inputs, do you mean you want to apply machine learning on user mouse-keyboard inputs? It's not going to work. Machine learning for chess requires hundreds and thousands of training set.

I think you should downplay the project and focus on something you can achieve.